# Showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-x} $ *doesn't* converge uniformly for $x \in (1,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

A question says, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-x} $ converges pointwise but not uniformly for $x \in (1,\infty)$. I can show it converges pointwise by taking $x\in (1+\delta, \infty)$ for any $x$ and $\delta>0$ and then using the Weierstrass-M test on $1+\delta$.

But I'm struggeling to show that it *doesn't* converge uniformly? Thanks!

Comment: Each partial sum is bounded, while the sum is unbounded on $(1,\infty)$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The series diverges to infinity as $x\rightarrow 1$.  In particular, for any $m$, we cannot bound $$\sum_{n=m}^\infty n^{-x}$$ uniformily, that is independently of $x$, for $x>1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I can't see how to show this directly?

Comment: @user26069: Tell me the exact definition of uniform convergence, and we can proceed from there.

Comment: $s_n \to a$ uniformly if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N = N(\epsilon)$ such that $(n \geq N$ and $x \in (1,\infty)) \implies |s_n - a| < \epsilon$

Comment: Where $s_n = \sum_{r=1}^n r^{-x}$

Comment: Is that right? Where do we go from here?

Comment: @user26069 For any partial sum, the supremum occurs when "x=1" (you can obtain the sup over $(1,\infty)$ by putting x=1)

Comment: Didn't realise this was over 10 Years old